# Adding own images to treeview levels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, treeview

I would like to add custom icons to the nodes of my treeview. In VB.NET, I can use an ImageList to contain the images for the treeview. However, in ASP.NET, this is not an option. I do not want to use the stock icons, as in the example below:

```
<asp:TreeViewTreeView ID="TreeView1" Runat="server"  
    Font-Underline="False" DataSourceId="XmlDataSource1"  
    CollapseImageUrl="Images/CollapseImage.gif"  
    ExpandImageUrl="Images/ExpandImage.gif"  
    LeafImageUrl="Images/LeafImage.gif">  
 <DataBindings>  
   <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Hardware" Text="Computer Hardware" />  
   <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Item" TextField="Category" />  
   <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Option" TextField="Choice" />  

  </DataBindings>  
</asp:TreeView>
```

How do I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Microsoft examples for Images in Treeview use below links for your answer

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagelist.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366759(v=vs.140).aspx